# Is there a way to have a Pygame object reach its destination at one speed, in the same amount of time, but visually move at another speed?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been setting up a game which is meant to have a "song speed" variable. I've set up the actual movement speed, and multiplied it by what is essentially Unity's Time.deltaTime, but the movement itself is very slow. Is there a way to keep a surface moving to the same position, in the same amount of time, but visually move faster.

Comment: The only possible way according to physics is to have a smaller screen x). Since a movement over a period of time is speed. You have to change one or both of these to perform what you want. The best solution is simply to increase the speed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the laws of physics, there are two possible ways of approaching this:

The first option is reducing the distance that the object is moving and increasing the speed, but according to your question that is not what you want (you said it needs to move to the same position, so I'm guessing the distance must be fixed).

If that doesn't work, then you should consider the second option - adding acceleration.

With fixed velocity movement, you only have three variables - distance, velocity, and time. That means that if you want two of them to be fixed but for the third to be changeable, it would be impossible. You could instead use movement that has a fixed **acceleration**, since that makes it speed up over time, making it seem like it's going faster.

Note that it doesn't have a constant speed so the speed itself would be getting higher with each frame.